# Using excel VBA open file based on cell value with path composed on the fly from same value

Tags: excel, vba

This is the goal.  User open’s read only workbook from network drive.  Selects a cell with the file name and clicks on macro button which will find and open how every many files there are that match the cell value.

What’s the most efficient method of achieving that result?  Keeping in mind that:

- User’s don’t want to wait for excel to compile a directory structure with files every time they open the workbook.
- file names will always match some portion of the containing folder name

  - file 135A1200 would be in folder 135A12XX
- dozens of folders/subfolders with varying levels of subfolders
- thousands of files with constant changes
- folder hierarchy is semi-permanent
- consistent file/folder naming format in that:

  - will always start with three numbers
  - followed by one to three letters
  - then four to seven numbers e.g., 135A1200 or 246FP317101
- didn’t want to use collections, etc. because of so many unknowns

I was thinking of having a loop of sorts that will take the value, build a path from that value while also verifying that the path exists before moving on, and then when the final sub-folder is reached, locate however many files that match the value and do whatever.  I’m having trouble with looping and adding the X’s in the sub-folders because they don’t match the selected value and it’s not always known where the X’s will be in a different sub-folder set.

135A1200-101 would equal \path\135\135A\135A1XXX\135A12XX\135A1200_S_01.file

Or

246FP317101-31 would equal \path\246\246F\246FP\246FP317101.file

- \\path\135\

  - 135A\

    - 135A0XXX\
    - 135A1XXX\
    - 135A10XX\
    - 135A11XX\
    - 135A12XX\

      - 135A1200_S_01.file
      - 135A1200_S_02.file
      - 135A1200_S_03.file
    - 135A13XX\
    - 135A3XXX\
    - 135ASKXXX\
  - 135D\
  - 135F\
  - 135GGG\
  - 135LL\
- \\path\321\
- \\path\246\

  - 246F\

    - 246F13\
    - 246F14\
    - 246F15\
    - 246F16\
    - 246FF\
    - 246FP\

      - 246FP317101.file

This is what I have which works ok for a simpler set of files and folders.

```
Public Sub pickFiles()
    Dim File As Variant
    Dim subPath As String

    File = Selection(1, 1).Value

    Select Case Left(File, 1)
    Case "Q"
        If Left(File, 6) = "Q11-12" Then
            subPath = "folder\QXX\Q11\" & Left(File, 6)
        ElseIf Left(File, 6) = "Q11-14" Then
            subPath = "folder\QXX\Q11\" & Left(File, 6)
        ElseIf Left(File, 6) = "Q11-22" Then
             subPath = "folder\QXX\Q11\" & Left(File, 6)
        Else
            subPath = "folder\QXX\" & Left(File, 3)
        End If
            openCompFile File, subPath
    Case "P"
        subPath = "folder\PXX\" & Left(File, 3)
        openCompFile File, subPath
    Case Else
        msgbox "That's not a valid file number", vbInformation
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub openCompFile(ByRef File As Variant, ByRef subPath As String)
    Dim mainPath As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim Folder As Folder
    'Dim File As Variant
    Dim FileCollection As New Collection

    mainPath = "X:\folder\" & subPath

    Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(mainPath)

    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If Left(File.Name, 9) = Left(File, 9) Then FileCollection.Add File
    Next File

    If FileCollection.Count = 0 Then
        msgbox Left(File, 9) & " was not found.", vbInformation
    Else
        For Each File In FileCollection
            ShellExecute 0, "Open", File.Path, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How does that even compile when openCompFile gets `ByRef File As Variant` passed into it and then attempts to declare `Dim File As Variant` as a local variable?

Comment: If you're having problems with the new code then it's probably more useful to post that instead of the version which works.

Comment: @Jeeped You're right.  That didn't belong there.

Comment: @Tim This is the only code I have.  Looking for guidance and just showing what I tried.

Comment: You say it works OK for a "simpler set of files" - in what way does it fail for a more complex set, and how does that set differ from the working set?  As long as you can look at the file name and reliably predict the path where the files will be found, it should be solvable: it just depends on the number and complexity of rules you need to follow.

Comment: It doesn't fail. It just becomes extremely cumbersome if I were to use dozens of select case statements like in my example. I'm not good with loops and trying to build a path as I've described is difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how fast this will be since it appears you are using a networked drive, but my thought would be to use Command's built in `DIR` function to find all the files. (Don't confuse this with VBA's built in DIR command. VBA DIR will not search subfolders. CMD's DIR will.)

I'm not 100% certain I know exactly what all your file names look like, but it appears that based on the sample data, that the portion of the filename to the left of the hyphen is always part of the filename for each file to be opened. for example: `135A1200-101` should always open the 3 files: `135A1200_S_01.file`, `135A1200_S_02.file`, and `135A1200_S_03.file`whereas `246FP317101-3` will open `246FP317101.file`. Assuming I understand the file naming conventions, is it true that `359AS12005-33` would open these files `359AS12005_S_05` and `359AS12005.file`?

If so, try out this code:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Function RunCMD(ByVal strCMD As String) As String
    'Runs the provided command
    Dim oShell As Object 'New wshShell
    Dim cmd As Object 'WshExec
    Dim x As Integer
    Const WshRunning = 0

    On Error GoTo wshError

    x = 0
    RunCMD = "Error"
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set cmd = oShell.Exec(strCMD)
    'Debug.Print strCMD
    'Stop
    Do While cmd.Status = WshRunning
        Sleep 100 'for 1/10th of a second
        x = x + 1
        If x > 1200 Then 'We've waited 2 minutes so kill it
            cmd.Terminate
            RunCMD = "Error: Timed Out"

        End If
    Loop

    RunCMD = cmd.StdOut.ReadAll & cmd.StdErr.ReadAll
    Set oShell = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Exit Function

wshError:
    RunCMD = cmd.StdErr.ReadAll
    Resume Next
End Function

Sub FindFiles()
    Dim strSearchResults As String
    Dim strBaseFileName As String
    Dim strFileName As Variant
    Dim arrFileNames As Variant

    strBaseFileName = Left(Selection(1, 1).Value, InStr(1, Selection(1, 1).Value, "-", vbTextCompare))
    strSearchResults = RunCMD("cmd /c ""Dir X:\folder\" & strBaseFileName & "* /a:-d /b /d /s""")
    Debug.Print strSearchResults
    'Split the results into an array the can be looped through
    arrFileNames = Split(strSearchResults, vbCrLf, -1, vbTextCompare)
    Debug.Print UBound(arrFileNames)
    For Each strFileName In arrFileNames
        Debug.Print strFileName
    Next
End Sub
```

Caveats: The FindFiles sub gets all the text up to the first hyphen and uses that to search *EVERY* subdirectory for *ANY* file starting with that string of text. If that's not what you're looking for, then hopefully this can point you towards a relatively efficient method of using the Windows DIR command (as opposed to VBA's DIR command which does NOT work in this case!) to find a solution.

Comment: This is great.  Let me work with it a bit to be sure.